# laravel pass query as parameter Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to pass a query as a parameter:

```php
$query = Users::where('name', 'John');
useQuery($query);

function useQuery($query) {
    $results = $query->get();
    ....
}
```

I get:

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Is there some way to pass a query to a function like this?

EDIT: I realized that the problem is at another place:

```php
class ExportCsv implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $filename;
    private $query;

    public function __construct($query, $filename)
    {
        $this->query = User::where('name', 'John'); // = $query
    }

...
}
```

The serialization error occurs here: `$this->query = User::where('name', 'John');`

Comment: What is your laravel version ?

Comment: In which line does this error pop-up?

Comment: Please post more code. What you have provided will not cause that error.

Comment: @jfadich I have updated the question